# save with multipe digits bit show two

Tags: django, python-2.6

I want to save in database with 10 decimals but only show 2 decimals in GUI.

Datatype does not matter.

Is there any easy way to do this?

Thanks
Henrik

Comment: with or without rounding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is actually twofold.

1. How to store the data?

   Do not store it as a CharField or something. Just store it as a [DecimalField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#decimalfield) or a [FloatField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FloatField).

   ```
   models.DecimalField(..., max_digits=20, decimal_places=10)
   ```
2. How to show only two decimals?

   Use the template tag [`floatformat`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/builtins/#floatformat) that takes the full value as input and outputs a decimal rounded with the number of decimals you want. In your case that would be `{{ value|floatformat:2 }}`.

Note that floats and decimal fields are [not the same](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#floatfield-vs-decimalfield).

---

[credit goes to [Burhan Khalid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/790387/burhan-khalid) for pointing out that a custom template tag is not needed]

Comment: You don't need to write a template tag, you can just use [`floatformat`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/builtins/#floatformat)

Comment: Thanks, just gonna fix back all my data into my db(:-)) and then I will try this. Get back to you.

Comment: @kingRauk To accept an answer you have to click on the 'V' below the up- and downvoting arrows.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way, if the datatype doesn't matter, is to store it as text in the database and then just parse the amount when you show it.

```
>>> silly = '12345.6789098765'
>>> silly[:silly.rfind('.')+3]
'12345.67'
```

Slightly more advanced; assuming you don't need precision:

```
>>> "{0:0.2f}".format(float(silly))
'12345.68'
```

Comment: Sometimes the 'easy way' is the difficult way on the long run.